# Django: Is there any way to have "unique for date range"?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**If my model for Items is:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    startDate = models.DateField("Start Date", unique="true")
    endDate = models.DateField("End Date")
```

Each *Item* needs to have a unique date range. for example, if i create an *Item* that has a date range of June 1st to June 8th, how can I keep and *Item* with a date range of June 3rd to June 5th from being created (or render an error with template logic)?

**PLEASE** let me know if I can clarify this question better!

Comment: @KillianDS I clicked that by accident, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not enforce this on the model level, you can however override the save method to 
something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    startDate = models.DateField("Start Date", unique="true")
    endDate = models.DateField("End Date")     

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            Item.objects.get(Q(startDate__range=(self.startDate,self.endDate))|Q(endDate__range=(self.sartDate,self.endDate))|Q(startDate__lt=self.startDate,endDate__gt=self.endDate))
            #raise some save error
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            super(Item,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

edit: maybe the date range check can go easier, long time since I did it, but it shows the general concept :).

Comment: +1 for enforcing this in the business logic layer, where it belongs

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I'll have to get back to this first thing in the morning.

Comment: I got this to work...but I don't know what to do after I raise the validation error. Can I make the error appear in the Admin after the user tries to save?

Comment: I think the best way is to throw an instance of `django.db.IntegrityError`, no ValidationError, the admin will know how to handle that. Another option is to move this to the clean method instead of the save method and throw a Validation Error (again the admin should cope). Note however the model clean method is supported only from django 1.2 on.

Answer (score 7):

If you use postgresql as a database backend and use a version of django >=3, you'll probably want to enforce this logic at the database level (this approach wasn't available when the accepted answer was given).

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.constraints import ExclusionConstraint
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField, RangeOperators
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_range = DateRangeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name='exclude_overlap',
                expressions=[
                    ('date_range', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
                ],
            )
```

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/constraints/